# Better memory consumption in java 10-12 than java 8?

Tags: java, spring

I tried to run the same spring application on different java versions and the results are:
(java version: memory consumption)
java 8: 478MB
java 10: 386MB
java 12: 282MB
Is their better memory consumption in the high versions of java?

Comment: You need to run the program for the same amount of time and workload, looking the highest used to get a meaningful comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the GC you are using.

In Java 9, G1 GC was made the default. 
You may check which GC you've used in Java 8 and other versions.

You can also improve the performance by configuring them using JVM flags.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM160

Comment: Nice to know, thanks. Is their any reason to the improvement in java 12 (in comparison to java 10)?

Comment: Improvements are being done in G1 GC
(1) to automatically return Java heap memory to the operating system when idle:
https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346 .

(2) to make G1 mixed collections abortable if they might exceed the pause target: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/344 .

There is also a new GC getting added: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/189 .

Hope this helps.. :)